# AWS match unsupported TLD domain name and S3 bucket static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, dns, cross-domain

I created aws S3 bucket as static web site. Everything works perfect. I've got the link like:

```
http://my-bucket-name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I have my own domain registred by local registrator, it's already works:

```
my-site.kiev.ua
```

This domain has some DNS servers settings

```
Name-server-1 ns1.servername.com
Name-server-2 ...
Name-server-3 ...
```

As I understand, I couldn't move 'kiev.ua' ukranian domain to aws. When I tried, I've got  the masssage:

```
UnsupportedTLD aws
```

How can I match this domain with aws S3 bucket static web site then? What I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a DNS in AWS to be able to serve a website through your domain.

Simpler option:
Create a CNAME record at your DNS provider and point it to the website URL of the S3 bucket that you have. Not 100% sure, but you might have an SSL problem because the S3 website doesn't have HTTPS

Better option:

1. Create the ACM certificate for your website (you will need to add a record in your DNS provider to confirm it)
2. Create a CloudFront distribution with Origin pointing to your S3 bucket.
3. Set Alternate Domain Name for your Distribution to `my-site.kiev.ua`
4. Copy the CloudFront Distribution DNS name that AWS generates and add a CNAME record in your DNS provider for `my-site.kiev.ua` to point to this DNS name

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for http protocol.
Create S3 bucket my-site.kiev.ua with public access and add S3 bucket policy (replace '[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]' with your actual bucket name):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
       "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow", 
        "Principal": "*", 
        "Action": "s3:GetObject", 
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/*" 
  } ] 
}
```

Then save and set static website hosting true.
Create [www.my-site.kiev.ua](http://www.my-site.kiev.ua) bucket without full access, just add redirect settings to previous bucket in static website hosting part.

Then go to Route 53 -> Hosted zones -> Create hosted zone. Name my-site.kiev.ua (Public hosted zone)
You will see new to fields with types NS and SOA. Copy 4 values from NS Value/Route traffic to and field by field match them with yours DNS-server settings (not in aws, on domain provider side).
Then press

```
Create record -> Simple routing -> Define simple record -> Match with S3 bucket my-site.kiev.ua -> Create records
```

And finally create the same record for www connection